# JavaScript sort() with localeCompare() doesn't work with passed parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

This is quite a bugger. I have this simple function which sorts an array of collections by one of its fields.

Here is a sample array:

```
"countries": [
    {
        "id": "AW",
        "name": "Aruba",
        "nameeng": "Aruba",
        "capital": "Oranjestad",
        "currency": "AWG",
        "phonecode": "297"
    },
    {
        "id": "BM",
        "name": "Bermuda",
        "nameeng": "Bermuda",
        "capital": "Hamilton",
        "currency": "BMD",
        "phonecode": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "GR",
        "name": "Ελλάδα",
        "nameeng": "Greece",
        "capital": "Athens",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "phonecode": "30"
    }];
```

It goes on longer but I guess you got the idea. And here is the function:

```
sortArray(source: any[], key) {

    let result = source.sort((a, b) => { 
        return a[String(key)].localeCompare(b[String(key)]); 
    });

    return result;
}
```

Now comes the mystery. If I invoke the function like this:

```
countries_sorted = sortArray(countries, 'nameeng');
```

then the result is chaos, the array elements are returned in a seemingly random order.

However, if I hardcode the field name into the function like this:

```
sortArray(source: any[], key) {
  let key = 'nameeng';
  ...
}
```

then it works perfectly!

I've checked it with `console.log()`, the parameter is handled properly, the type is String. Yet the sorting doesn't happen if I pass it, only if I hardcode it.

Lodash is not a solution because it can't sort accented characters.

Comment: just fyi (not related to your problem) .. `.sort()` sorts the array in place, so, no need to `let result = .....; return result` - you can just `return source.sort....`

Comment: @JaromandaX since the method sorts the array in place, is a `return` needed at all?

Comment: depends on how you use the function I guess, @GerardoFurtado - I wouldn't return myself, but ... use case?

Comment: The function is actually in an Angular service and it's called from a component.

Comment: It may well be there's other code not posted that changes the order, perhaps that's worth looking at, because, the code **as posted** works as expected

Comment: try `let result = source.slice().sort(.....` to return a sorted **copy** of the array

Comment: No, there is no other code. I stripped it bare and removed everything. It's what you can see here. The problem still persists.

Comment: Jaromanda X, thanks, that worked! Interestingly, `Object.assign()` didn't do the trick.